# Open source Package of R?

Tags: r, package, open-source

I used the packages "tm", "lda" and "topicmodels" in R.

Is there open source code for these packages (in other language(s)) so that I could modify the core??

Comment: Each package available from CRAN is open-source. Look at the corresponding CRAN page under "Package source": http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/index.html

Comment: Packages do not modify the core, they add to it. Most `R` packages are written in `R`.

Comment: I get a result by using LDA and CTM,now i am going to call my commandes in R from java.
Will be helpful "Topic Modeling - Mallet" for me to having the same reuslt that i have now in R?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function

Answer (score 6):

Every package on CRAN (the main R archive) has a link to the source code. e.g.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lda/index.html

lists:

```
Reference manual:   lda.pdf
Package source:     lda_1.3.2.tar.gz
MacOS X binary:     lda_1.3.2.tgz
Windows binary:     lda_1.3.2.zip
Old sources:    lda archive
```

download the package source, extract it (7-zip will extract tar.gz archives on Windows, I think) and there will be the source code.